# Angular JS Routing is not working in ASP.NET MVC and Web API project

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-routing

I have two main ASP.NET MVC controllers: `Home` and `User`. `Home` has an `Index` method that is returning an `Index` view which is main page for loading partial pages (User Detail, Facility, Login Page) in ng-view. Also, Index view is not using MVC layout. My solution explorer looks like this

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJYzQ.png)]

Issue is, when I run application, partial pages are not loading in ng-View and URL is not forming correctly.

My `Module.js` looks like this

```
/// <reference path="../scripts/angular.js" />
var app = angular.module('ApplicationModule', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    //alert('Im Config');
    $routeProvider.when('/Login',
        {
            templateUrl: 'User/Login',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        })
        .when('/Profile',
            {
                templateUrl: 'User/UserDetail',
                controller: 'ProfileController'
            })
        .when('/Facility',
            {
                templateUrl: 'User/Facility',
                controller: 'FacilityController'
            })
        .otherwise(
            {
            redirectTo: 'User/UserDetail'
            });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

My `Controller.js` looks like this:

```
/// <reference path="../scripts/angular.js" />
/// <reference path="module.js" />

app.controller("LoginController", function ($scope, $http) {
    alert("Login Controller Called");
}); 
app.controller("ProfileController",  function ($scope, $http) {
    alert("profile Controller Called");
});

app.controller("FacilityController",  function ($scope, $http) {
    alert("Facility controller called");
});
```

`Index.cshtml` looks like this

```
<div>
    <h1>header</h1>
</div>

<div class="main container" ng-view>
    <div>
        <a href="#/Login">Login</a>
        <a href="#/Profile">Profile</a>
        <a href="#/Facility">Facility</a>
    </div>

</div>

<footer class="footer py-4 bg-dark text-light">
    <h1>Footer</h1>
</footer>
```

Output is as follows:

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQfcL.png)]

Login, profile and facility partial views are not loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AngularJS version 1.6 they changed the hash-prefix for URL hash-bang. Links now have `#!` instead of `#`.

so try with this

```
<div>
  <a href="#!Login">Login</a>
  <a href="#!Profile">Profile</a>
  <a href="#!Facility">Facility</a>
</div>
```

Or if you want to remove the hash-prefix (`!`), you would need your config to have this code:

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

More about it: [commit-aa077e8](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8)